# compiling code in netbeans

Tags: java

I installed Java, but for some reason NetBeans wont compile my code, I am getting error:

```
C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Key Stroke Project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:609: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\Key Stroke Project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:250: Error running ${platform.javac} compiler
```

Any ideas?

The line is:

```
target="${javac.target}" tempdir="${java.io.tmpdir}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Open a command shell and type `javac -version`.  You should see the version of Java you installed echoed back.

If the operating system complains about not being able to find the `javac.exe` command, then you need to add `JAVA_HOME/bin` to your PATH.

If you don't have a `JAVA_HOME/bin`, then perhaps you installed the JRE instead of JDK by mistake.

You may need to tell NetBeans how to find Java as well.  I'm an IntelliJ user, so I can't be of much help there.